# React app Not playing fragmented mp4 chunks in IPad

Tags: reactjs, ipad, html5-video

I have a react component to play fragmented mp4 chunks in  tag.
The mp4 chunks are received in websocket on message. below code is used to create "src" from received chunk.

```js
onMessage(event) {
    const chunk = event.data;
    this.setState({
         chunks: [...this.state.chunks, chunk],
    });
    if (this.state.chunks.length === 1) {
        this.videoRef.current.src = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(this.state.chunks));
    }
}
```

Video tag is given as below.

```html
<video
   id="video"
   width={800}
   height={800}
   ref={this.videoRef}
   autoPlay
   playsInline
   controls
   muted
   loop
/>
```

This code is working in WindowsPC, Linux android tab. But not working in iPad (safari and Chrome)

Could you please help me to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

I was expecting to play fragmented mp4 chunks in all environment with this code.